# Can't restore Windows 11 after changing BIOS RAID (RST) to AHCI

Tags: windows, ahci

I need to change my BIOS to AHCI to support a dual-boot Windows/Linux configuration.

I took care to create a Windows 11 System Image on an external drive and a System Repair DVD before doing anything else.

[image]

However, after making the change, and then using the System Repair disc to restore my system image, my laptop won't recognize the drive! What can I do to recover my system image after this change please?

Comment: How did you image your OS? Did you use Linux `dd` to create an exact image?

Comment: Windows 11 won't run the old way.

Comment: It's impossible for Linux to even see the drives in RST mode, so dd is not possible, or even gparted.
Windows certainly will run in either UEFI or RST/RAID mode. In fact, right now I'm running it with UEFI, but I had to lose my apps in the process so I'd like to reinstall with the System Image if possible.

Comment: @brian
I've updated my original post to illustrate how I created the system image.
It's a standard Windows tool, and I presumed that it would restore to a disk no matter whether it was in RAID or UEFI mode.

Comment: @bob, `dd` should be possible. you just need to install `mdadm` on linux to search and mount RST. But, that is a moot point for this matter. When you say the computer won't recognize the drive, are you referring to the internal drive or the external drive where you saved your image?

Comment: As in FYI to future readers, it appears that dual boot is possible with RST. When installing the Linux variant, be sure to install `mdadm` to first recognize the MS RST. https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: Regarding the FYI - in that case, shouldn't gparted Live have mdadm installed by default?
Regarding my issue - after restoring Windows to my internal drive (from my external image), it won't boot and says the internal drive is not recognized.

Comment: Also, RST appears to be pretty standard these days. Dell computers have shipped with it enabled for several years now for example. So why doesn't Ubuntu 22.04 have support baked in? My Live installer couldn't see the drives in that mode. Is `mdadm` not considered as stable enough?

Comment: As for mdadm, I don't know what it isn't installed by default. I have been using it for over a decade with any problems.

Comment: I haven't used Windows system image feature myself so take the folllowing witha  grain of salt. I wonder if the system image includes the hidden partitions Windows 10/11 require to boot correctly. Perhaps, system image assumes you are merely restoring and image to the same computer after a corruption and the hidden partitions are still present.

Comment: Boot to Ubuntu Live and in the terminal do `fdisk -l` and find your internal disck. Once you find your disk (likely something `/dev/sdX`, `fdisk` into it (i.e. `fdisk /dev/sdX`. Once you do that, you should see what partitions it has.. I doubt any since you changes to AHCI in the BIOS. (I'm still researching whether the system image includes those hidden partitions)

Comment: Before you disable Intel RST within UEFI did you uninstall the Intel RST drivers?  Did you install your sysem on a Intel RST RAID or was Intel RST simply enabled? Please provide the required information to answer your question.

Comment: Before disabling RST, if I were to uninstall the RST drivers in Windows, I'm pretty sure Windows could no longer access the disk so that doesn't sound like a good plan. I would think that I would want to install AHCI drivers instead. Windows should know how to use an appropriate driver and not to use drivers which aren't relevant. But I would also expect AHCI drivers to be available by default. I restored my RST config and image and am back to square one. I like the link Brian posted above and think I'll follow that.

Comment: After looking into this more deeply, and reflecting on my experience with hardware RAID controllers, I believe that `mdadm` is a command-line utility for managing software/OS-based RAID solutions for multi-disk systems. It does not require (and is incompatible with) hardware RAID-controller support. You'll note there is no mention of RST on the `mdadm` man page or in the links above. RST refers to Intel's hardware-based RAID controller which requires different drivers and I can find no indication of support for it in Linux at this time. So even with `mdadm` I don't believe Linux supports RST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who posted links and shared information.
My problem was in not doing a safe boot so that Windows had a chance to install an AHCI driver before fully coming up.

Thanks to @brian for this link: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347/1

And this much more concise and easier-to-follow documentation on the Dell website:
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124714/how-to-switch-from-ahci-to-raid-on-dell-data-security-windows-systems

I did ***not*** follow the information regarding changing registry keys - it was not necessary in my case. The interim safe boot was sufficient for Windows to recognize the BIOS change and switch to using the necessary driver.

There's some significant misinformation in earlier comments which I why I felt it important to test the process and provide this answer myself.

I switched BIOS back to RAID and restored my Windows System recovery image, to get back to my initial state. Then I followed this process:

1. open an elevated command prompt and run command `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
2. Reboot the computer. Press F2 during reboot to enter BIOS settings mode.
3. In BIOS, modify SATA Operation from RAID to AHCI
4. Exit the BIOS and restart the computer. Windows automatically boots into safe mode and updates the required driver.
5. Still in safe mode, open another command prompt and run command `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
6. Reboot and allow Windows to start normally.